# name for parameter that overrides other values

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

it's a clean-code type question.

application sends emails on appropriate addresses. but when variable X is set, it overrides all email addresses. all emails are sent to the address specified in X. variable X is being read from config file during deployment time and set by IoC container
sth like:

```java
public class EmailSender {

    @Value("config.option.X")
    private String X;

    public void sendEmail() {
        ...
        if (X != null) message.setEmailAddress(X);
        internalEmailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

and i have no idea how to name X properly. replacerEmailAddress? emailAddressOverrider? any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the context in which variable X is set?  I would try and name it to reference that condition in some way.

Comment: it's set in configuration file that is read during deployment. i'll write some more details in my question

Comment: I guess I was more referring to what is the business reason for the override email address being set?  If there's a succinct reason for it to be set, try and name the variable using that reason somehow.

Comment: oh. it's for test. our application sends email to users but on dev and UAT we want it to send mails on one specific address instead of spam users

Comment: Maybe "testModeEmailAddress" then?

Comment: that's one option but i'm not sure if i want to do that since this parameter will be present also in production configuration files. it will be just empty

Comment: Is a single instance of an EmailSender created for each email to be sent?  If that's the case you could use some form of dependency injection to pass in the email address via a constructor or setter.  That would help you separate code specific from testing from being present in production code in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's look like default option.

So i will name this like that:

public class EmailSender {

```
@Value("config.option.defaultEmailValue")
private String defaultEmailValue;

public void sendEmail() {
    ...
    if (defaultEmailValue != null){
        message.setEmailAddress(defaultEmailValue);
    } 
    internalEmailSender.send(message);
}
```

}